# PHP Regex Match from Start to First Occurrence

Tags: php, regex

I have a string say
**$str**  -  `This is my test string that needs to be matched and not the test keywords following it`

**Output** - `This is my test`

But my Regex pattern : (.*?)test

is matching till last.
Kindly help how to achieve the same

Comment: [Cannot confirm at all in any PHP version](http://3v4l.org/pc284)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this simple regex:

```
^.*?test
```

OR better not use regex and use `strpos` String functions.

```
$pos = strrpos($str, "test", 0);
if ($pos === true) {
    // found...
}
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks, that worked. But can you please explain why mine didn't work with the parenthesis? Or what was wrong there?

Comment: Problem with your regex: `(.*?)test` is **absence** of line start anchor `^`

Comment: ok .. 1 more thing.. what if my first test word is in the second line.
It doesnt match it then...
For ex : 
`This is`
`my test string`

Comment: http://regexr.com?373vh

Comment: @anubhava The `^` anchor *shouldn't* be needed: [demo](http://3v4l.org/pc284)

Comment: @var17 Add the PCRE_DOTALL `/s` modifier in your regex (`/[a-z]/` becomes `/[a-z]/s`)

Comment: @h2ooooooo: Thanks yes `s` flag is needed for making `dot` match `new line`.